# im trying to load two separate divs from same external source

Tags: jquery, html, load, external

hi I want to load header and content data from external HTML but when I do it the way I do it, nav links don't work after one click.. but all links work in the first try. after clicking one link, others don't work.. here is what I'm doing:

```
$( "#home" ).click(function() {

    $( "#header" ).load( "index.html #header" );
    $( "#wholepage" ).load( "index.html #wholepage" );

});

$( "#threed" ).click(function() {

    $( "#header" ).load( "3d.html #header" );
    $( "#wholepage" ).load( "3d.html #wholepage" );

});

$( "#photo" ).click(function() {

    $( "#header" ).load( "photo.html #header" );
    $( "#wholepage" ).load( "photo.html #wholepage" );

});

$( "#blog" ).click(function() {

    $( "#header" ).load( "blog.html #header" );
    $( "#wholepage" ).load( "blog.html #wholepage" );

});

$( "#about" ).click(function() {

    $( "#header" ).load( "about.html #header" );
    $( "#wholepage" ).load( "about.html #wholepage" );

});
```

if I load either header or whole page(btw whole page is everything apart from the header) but it doesn't work if I try to load both together. I click a menu item once, it works and then nothing.

Comment: There might be some id overlapping happening. Check your html code after importing.

Comment: mmm i don't think so but ill check later, i gotta sleep now.. do u think the script is correct otherwise?

Comment: The portion of the script you shared, looks correct to me.

Comment: thats all of it.. i tried adding document ready but didnt have any affect

Comment: i just checked.. even though it successfully loads the new content from external html, it still shows the source code of original file :)

Comment: anyways dont bother coz ill just go with traditional html links coz it doesnt keep the loaded content once the page is refreshed.. thnx